# Pynsist project can't find default Python after installation

Tags: python, pyqt5, nsis, pynsist

I have built a GUI using `PyQt5` and wanted to distribute it to other computers without `Python` installed by packageing it with `pynsist`.
Unfortunately, the default `Python`, which does exist in the 'Python'-folder of the installation (and which is executable), cannot be found.

I first thought that there must be a problem with the paths `pynsist` was generating for the shortcut, but it is targeting the right path to `pythonw.exe` (I am using Python without a terminal) and the `.launch.pyw` file, which correctly triggers the `main()` function of the script.
E.g. `C:\install_GUI\Python\pythonw.exe 'C:\install_GUI\GUI.launch.pyw'`

When trying to start the script directly (not using the shortcut) I get the warning message 'Can't find a default Python'.

Any suggestions what causes this problem and how to make it work?

Could this issue be related to the coding of the scripts?
This means I have included `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on top of each script, but the automatically generated `.launch.pyw` file comes without this line.
I know that `Python` above version 3 has `utf-8` coding as a default, but without adding this line to the `.launch.pyw` file the GUI does not even work on my computer after installation (using Python 3.6.5).

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: How is this NSIS related?

Comment: I thought it is relevant since `pynsist` uses NSIS to create the installer and to define the paths (which might cause the problem).

Comment: I suspect that the "can't find a default Python" message mean that the `py` and `pyw` launchers are installed on the machine and associated with the `.py` and `.pyw` file types. The launchers are designed to run files using a Unix style `#!` line at the start of the file. If that's not there, they're probably looking for a default Python installation in the registry. The bundled copy of Python with your app is not registered in the registry. In that situation, I think you probably have to either use the shortcut, or launch it from the command prompt using an explicit path to `pythonw.exe`.

Comment: The launchers were previously installed, but are now uninstalled on this test-computer. Thanks for the tip, I deleted the associations in the registry for the `.py` and `.pyw` files. Unfortunately, when launching the shortcut Python keeps crashing. The `.launch.pyw` files of my build contain the `#!` line and should actually work, but still can't be run; neither by using the shortcut or the console. In respect of the end-users I need to make it work just by using the shortcut.